# Role doesn't get added autorole | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, roles

```
autoroles = {}

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  global autoroles
  with open("autorole.json", "r") as f:
      autoroles = json.load(f)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    #my welcome command is also here
    await member.add_roles(autoroles[member.guild])

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def autorole(ctx, *, role : discord.Role=None):
  
  embed=discord.Embed(color=0x7289da, description=f"**Set autorole to** {role.mention}**?**")
  embed.set_footer(text="React with the wave reaction to confirm it!")
  msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

  def checkifnotbot(reaction, user):
      return user != client.user

  await msg.add_reaction('')

  reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60.0, check=checkifnotbot)

  if str(reaction.emoji) == "":   

    embedw=discord.Embed(description=f"**Autorole set!**\n> Everytime someone joins the server they get the {role.mention} role!", color=0x7289da)     
    await msg.edit(embed=embedw)
    await msg.clear_reactions()
    
    global autoroles
    autoroles[str(ctx.guild.id)] = role.id

    with open("autorole.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(autoroles, f)
```

**What i want to happen:** If someone uses the autorole command, the role gets added once someone joins the server (It's for multiple discord servers)
**The problem:** I don't get any errors, but the role just doesnt get added. I think its because .add_roles doesn't want an id but a role object. But i have no clue how to do this
**Note:** The setup works, it gets added to the json file https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzbv6.jpg
**I also tried this:** https://pastebin.com/eCp4HN7F

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems in your code, one is getting the id of the role from the json, and the other is adding the role. For adding the role you need to specify the `discord.Role` for it to work correctly.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, 
    id=autoroles[str(member.guild.id)])
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

See that I am using `str(member.guild.id)` as your key of the json is a string. This will also support multiple autoroles.

### References:

- [utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get)
- [add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles)

Comment: Thanks! This is what i have now https://pastebin.com/fF6PQWHv but this still doesnt work

Comment: Are you getting an error, and what intents do you have enabled?

Comment: I don't get an error, and i have server member intent enabled.

Comment: Got it to work, but now it only works when they also enabled the welcome messages since they bot use the same event decorator. https://pastebin.com/JCwkUxZ7